# Symfony2 use multiple role hierarchies

Tags: symfony, hierarchy, role

I have two firewalls (front & backoffice) configured in security.yml.

I would like to use two different role hierarchies, stored in database.

I created a RoleHierarchy class and used a service for the back office, it works well.
But how can I declare a second service for the front office?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I find a way to deal with my problem.
I had to develop 2 Voters, following the documentation : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html.

Each Voter use its own RoleHierarchy.